# Django iregex to get best search using filter

Tags: python, django, regex

> I'm searching the title field using django filter uisng title__iregex
> and not able to get best result, can anyone help me creating best
> possible regex/ regular expression for the title search.
>
> Example: Search may be --> how are you OR hw are u OR how r you .

```
Book.objects.filter(title__iregex=r'.*' + 'z b')
```

Comment: i do not think regex is best suited here...you probably need NLP

Comment: As I can not use NLP as per now, so could you suggest me the regex for a title which can consider cases and space example. The best Book or best book